# Positioning a submit button along with CSS stars to create a rating form

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a rating form - and I am struggling to get the Submit button to align "nicely",with my CSS stars.

Ideally, I want my page to look something like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
|                          * * * * * Submit                |
|                                                          |
|-----------------------------------------------------------
|                                                          |
|            BOTTOM PART                                   |
|                                                          |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Where the form and it's components (i.e. button and stars), behave like a cohesive unit, and can be moved along the X and Y axis, as a single group.

This is what I have managed to come up with so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <style>
        .rate {
            display: inline-block;
            position: relative;
            height: 20px;
            line-height: 20px;
            font-size: 20px;
        }
        
        .rate label {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            height: 100%;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        
        .rate label:last-child {
            position: static;
        }
        
        .rate label:nth-child(1) {
            z-index: 5;
        }
        
        .rate label:nth-child(2) {
            z-index: 4;
        }
        
        .rate label:nth-child(3) {
            z-index: 3;
        }
        
        .rate label:nth-child(4) {
            z-index: 2;
        }
        
        .rate label:nth-child(5) {
            z-index: 1;
        }
        
        .rate label input {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            opacity: 0;
        }
        
        .rate label .icon {
            float: left;
            color: transparent;
        }
        
        .rate label:last-child .icon {
            color: #CACACA;
        }
        
        .rate:not(:hover) label input:checked ~ .icon,
        .rate:hover label:hover input ~ .icon {
            color: #ffd900;
        }
        
        .rate label input:focus:not(:checked) ~ .icon:last-child {
            color: #000;
            text-shadow: 0 0 5px #ffd900;
        }    
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <form class="rate">

                    <label title="Poor">
                        <input type="radio" name="stars" value="1"/>
                        <span class="icon">★</span>
                    </label>
                    <label title="Below average">
                        <input type="radio" name="stars" value="2"/>
                        <span class="icon">★</span>
                        <span class="icon">★</span>
                    </label>
                    <label title="Average">
                        <input type="radio" name="stars" value="3"/>
                        <span class="icon">★</span>
                        <span class="icon">★</span>
                        <span class="icon">★</span>   
                    </label>
                    <label title="Above average">
                        <input type="radio" name="stars" value="4"/>
                        <span class="icon">★</span>
                        <span class="icon">★</span>
                        <span class="icon">★</span>
                        <span class="icon">★</span>
                    </label>
                    <label title="Excellent">
                        <input type="radio" name="stars" value="5"/>
                        <span class="icon">★</span>
                        <span class="icon">★</span>
                        <span class="icon">★</span>
                        <span class="icon">★</span>
                        <span class="icon">★</span>
                    </label>
                    <!-- button class="btn-info btn btn-sm pull-right">Submit</button>-->
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                Bottom part
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

How do I fix the markup/CSS so that:

1. The button is correctly positioned to the right of the stars in the form
2. The starts and the button can be 'moved' as a single unit along the X,Y axis - by setting margin etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should help you?

```js
var unit = document.getElementById("wrapper");

function moveMeX() {
  unit.style.marginLeft = "130px";

}

function moveMeY() {
  unit.style.marginTop = "130px";

}
```

```css
.rate {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.rate label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.rate label:last-child {
  position: static;
}

.rate label:nth-child(1) {
  z-index: 5;
}

.rate label:nth-child(2) {
  z-index: 4;
}

.rate label:nth-child(3) {
  z-index: 3;
}

.rate label:nth-child(4) {
  z-index: 2;
}

.rate label:nth-child(5) {
  z-index: 1;
}

.rate label input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.rate label .icon {
  float: left;
  color: transparent;
}

.rate label:last-child .icon {
  color: #CACACA;
}

.rate:not(:hover) label input:checked~.icon,
.rate:hover label:hover input~.icon {
  color: #ffd900;
}

.rate label input:focus:not(:checked)~.icon:last-child {
  color: #000;
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px #ffd900;
}


/* changes */

.row {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#stars label {
  padding-top: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <form class="rate">
        <div id="wrapper">
          <div id="stars">
            <label title="Poor">
                            <input type="radio" name="stars" value="1" />
                            <span class="icon">★</span>
                        </label>
            <label title="Below average">
                            <input type="radio" name="stars" value="2" />
                            <span class="icon">★</span>
                            <span class="icon">★</span>
                        </label>
            <label title="Average">
                            <input type="radio" name="stars" value="3" />
                            <span class="icon">★</span>
                            <span class="icon">★</span>
                            <span class="icon">★</span>
                        </label>
            <label title="Above average">
                            <input type="radio" name="stars" value="4" />
                            <span class="icon">★</span>
                            <span class="icon">★</span>
                            <span class="icon">★</span>
                            <span class="icon">★</span>
                        </label>
            <label title="Excellent">
                            <input type="radio" name="stars" value="5" />
                            <span class="icon">★</span>
                            <span class="icon">★</span>
                            <span class="icon">★</span>
                            <span class="icon">★</span>
                            <span class="icon">★</span>
                        </label>
          </div>
          <button class="btn-info btn btn-sm pull-right">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      Bottom part
    </div>
  </div>


  <!--delete me !-->
  <button onclick="moveMeX()">'moved' as a single unit along the X axis</button>
  <button onclick="moveMeY()">'moved' as a single unit along the Y axis</button>

</body>

</html>
```

- please note that I Override the style of **row** class

I hope this helps! Let me know if it worked for you, cheers!

Comment: Thanks very much. I think you might have misunderstood what I meant by "Moved as a groupE along the X/Y axis.

I simply meant that by using CSS selectors, I could specify (i.e adjust) where I wanted the group (i.e. the form) to be positioned. So since the form has class "rate". I want to be able to apply a style like `frm.rate { margin: 20px 5px  5px 20px; }`  and have all the components in the form moved together.

Comment: try to add  `form.rate{margin: 39px 5px 5px 20px;}`  it will move all the components in the form   together.